# Disputes over Biblical Laws

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, communities

I would like to compile an extensive list of **Biblical** laws that are debated by **current** halachik authorities in the Orthodox community as to whether or not they are Biblical laws, Ribbinic laws, or simply permissible.

I understand that many potentially-Biblical laws have been debated, and sometimes settled in the Talmud, Rishonim, and halachik codifiers over the ages. I am interested to know which potentially-Biblical laws are still debated by Rabbis or communities today, that can lead to differences of practice.

I am not interested in Rabbinic laws or customs (i.e. definitely not Biblical according to all authorities); there are thousands of disputes concerning those. I want to know about **Biblical** laws, which seem to have fewer debates within the Orthodox community.

Comment: (a) Do you mean that you are looking for discussions of the differences between the counts (of Rambam, Ramban, etc.) of the _Mitzvot min ha-Torah_? (b) "_I understand that many potentially-Biblical laws have been debated, and sometimes settled, in the Talmud_ ...". You understand from whom, where (especially concerning debates in the Talmud, as to whether something is a Biblical law)?

Comment: Why did you delete this? It's a reasonable question.

Comment: I don't know if the other question is the same, because that question is looking for permissible vs, Biblical, whereas I'm looking for permissible, Rabbinic, and Biblical. Also, my question is a lot simpler, universal, and clearer than his roundabout, limited, and  confusing question.

Comment: When you say "Biblical laws", do you mean _Mitzvot_, or more general _Halakhot_? (My previous comment understood you to mean the former, but the discussion around the linked question suggests the latter.)